# From AWS API creating a new EC2 instance, how do I get a public ip

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Through the AWS Java API I am building a new EC2 instance, from scratch.  I can create a new VPC, subnet, and security group, and then pass them to in a RunInstanceRequest to API's runInstance(), and I get back a running EC2 instance.

What I have not figured out is how to get a public IP assigned to this new EC2 instance.  I have gone through the documentation and it appears I internetGateway, which I can create, but can not figure out how to associate it with the VPC or the instance itself.

On RunInstance object, I located the .withNetworkInterfaces method, which does take a NetworkInstanceSpecfication, which has a flag for enabling a public id, but this asks for a deviceId(int), which I do not know how to build or create.

Does anyone have any advice or material they can point me too, which can help with my issue?

Do I need to create a NAT, routing table, elastic ip, etc. for this functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955977/how-to-obtain-the-public-ip-address-on-ec2-launch-instance-request/34956198#34956198

Answer (score 0):

For beginner, please study [VPC scenarios](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenarios.html).

What you need to do is put internetGateway IGW inside designated VPC route table.

By default, all new subnet `Auto-assign Public IP` attributes is false. To make your subnet assign public IP address to Ec2 instance, you must use `ModifySubnetAttribute` and set `MapPublicIpOnLaunch` to true.

From there's on, all EC2 instance launched in the subnet will automatically assigned with public IP address.

Comment: I reread the link, and I understand your comment, I am just at a lost on how to get from a VPC to its routing table through the Java API.  I have done this in the past, but only through the web interface.

Comment: Using API to create VPC layout is pretty time consuming. I suggest you investigate options such as Terraform. AWS will suggest cloudformation, a high learning curve options.

Comment: Yes, I am getting that feeling about the time.  I will be playing with Terraform soon, I was just trying to see if I could do straight through the API first, but  It sounds as if I should move on, and look at other options, like Terraform.